# Where to find output? Spring + H2 Tutorial

Tags: spring, tomcat, h2

This should be a basic question, but I'm not getting it. I am working through this tutorial to see how Spring and H2 interact: https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

At the end, I have generated a .war file. I can run my Tomcat server with this code on it, but I'm not sure where to look to find the "output", like is posted at the end of the tutorial.

How do I view that output? I have my H2 database running locally, but it doesn't look like anything is happening their either. What did I miss?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you're using executable jar approach as described in the tutorial, it should come right away into your stdout in your console.

But if you use a tomcat server, then you have to browse the logs folder. The actual file might depends on your logging configuration but normally a file that has "stdout" on its name.